# RecyclerView not working with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I try to create a HORIZONTAL recyclerView but recyclerView can't find the context here is my Fragmnet code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.context =context;
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);

    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryModels = null;

    RecyclerView recyclerView = container.findViewById(R.id.category_recycler);
   // recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(context,CategoryData.getCategory());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
}
```

and here is Recycler view adapter code:

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<CategoryModel> categorys;
    public CategoryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryModels) {
        this.categorys = categoryModels;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull

    @Override
    public CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.product_category,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }
```

i'm also attached the Debug result please check the image[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Defines the xml file for the fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryModels = null;

        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.category_recycler);
        // recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(getContext(), CategoryData.getCategory());
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `Context` inside `Fragment` use `getContext()` method .

```
CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(getContext(),CategoryData.getCategory());
```

From [official](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getContext()) doc

> Return the Context this fragment is currently associated with.

If you are using `Context` only for inflating view inside `onCreateViewHolder` method in `CategoryAdapter` class then you don't need to pass `Context` in Constructor. You can get `Context` from `ViewGroup` which is first parameter of the `onCreateViewHolder` method.

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_category,parent,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate()` fragment callback I see this line:

> ```
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     ...
>     this.context =context;
>     ...
> }
> ```

This line doesn't do anything; there's no `context` argument to the `onCreate()` method or anything like that, so you're just assigning a variable back to itself. Since your `Context context` field doesn't have an explicit intialization, the default is `null`. So this is the same as writing

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    this.context = null;
    ...
}
```

Later on, in `onCreateView()`, you're instantiating your adapter with this line:

> ```
> CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(context,CategoryData.getCategory());
> ```

Because of what I said above, this is functionally the same as

```
CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(null, CategoryData.getCategory());
```

To solve this, you need some place to get a `Context` instance from. Fragments are often "attached" to a context, and, when they're attached, you can get that context by calling `getContext()`. A fragment is guaranteed to be attached to a context in the `onActivityCreated()` callback, so you will want to move your adapter creation to that callback instead of `onViewCreated()`.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(getContext(), CategoryData.getCategory());

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.category_recycler);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}
```

Comment: i already try this CategoryAdapter(getContext() ,CategoryData.getCategory()) and CategoryAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),CategoryData.getCategory()); not working  :(

Comment: Did you try it in `onActivityCreated()` instead of in `onCreateView()`?